# jQuery fade Toggle don't stop toggling

Tags: jquery, toggle, fade

on my project, the toggle function toggles multiple times. I think it's because of an absolute positioned div which should fade in an out. I can't solve that...

Here the jQuery-Code:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){
$j('.grit_1_3_1').hover(
    function(){$j('.grit_1_3_1_hover').fadeIn()}, 
    function(){$j('.grit_1_3_1_hover').fadeOut()}
);
});
```

Here the css for the divs:

```
.grit_1_3_1 {
color: #ffffff;
width: 33%;
float: left;
background: #bdbdbd;
vertical-align: center;
text-align: center;
height: 296px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.grit_1_3_1_hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 296px;
    display: none;

    float: left;
    background: #bdbdbd;
    vertical-align: center;
    text-align: center;
    height: 296px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

The first of the 3 teaser should toggle, but doesn't stop!

Thanks for your help!

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('.grit_1_3_1').hover(function() {
        $j('.grit_1_3_1_hover').stop.fadeTo(1);
    }, function() {
        $j('.grit_1_3_1_hover').stop().fadeTo(0);
    });
});​
```

### Edit,

Actually, your HTML/CSS as also incorrect when the mouse is over `.grit_1_3_1`, `.grit_1_3_1_hover` completely overlaps `.grit_1_3_1`. Thus, that means the mouse is now out of `.grit_1_3_1` and it fade back out.

Instead of showing/hiding `grit_1_3_1_hover` I recommend you create 2 divs at the child level `grit_content` and `grit_content_hover` then modify your code to

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('.grit_1_3_1').hover(function() {
        $j('.grit_content_hover', $(this)).stop.fadeTo(1);
    }, function() {
        $j('.grit_content_hover', $(this)).stop.fadeTo(0);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `.fadeIn()` the `_hover` div, it replaces the original `<div>` on screen, which causes your mouse to leave that `<div>`, triggering the second part of the `.hover()` call.

Rather than swapping the divs, it may be simpler to just swap the text *contents* of those divs.

Alternatively, use an `absolute` positioned `<div>` overlay on top of the two alternating divs.  Have *that* div handle the `hover` action, but then have the required div below show through it.

Comment: You are both right. It did it now. 2 divs within the content. My original Code works here, Atif Mohammed's didn't work though. But at least it works now. THANKS!